# Content fitting div vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering the best way to automatically have content vertically fit a container (preferably using CSS, but other suggestions are welcome). So, for example, similar to having equal top / bottom spacing (padding / margin) between item (in my case, an `<img>` followed by various text tags) inside a div. The goal would be that the content gracefully stretches to fit the container.

I've been looking around but haven't found a decent solution, or any recent questions about this (though admittedly I could've looked harder). Thanks

Per Louie Almeda's suggestion, here's an illustration:

[image]

Comment: This will be best described with an image or link to an image

Comment: @LouieAlmeda Good idea--just updated to include one.

Comment: @LouieAlmeda actually, this would be best fitted with a coding attempt. Consider reading [ask] before giving advice, especially to newcomers. Aristoatle, please update with what you have tried. Do note [so] is not a free coding service.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well the relevant code is pretty trivial (just a few tags and a default `align-items: stretch` to determine the height of the divs). I should have clarified I was wondering if there was a defacto solution to this problem (e.g., something with flexbox I'm overlooking), but I'm not expecting an elaborate or hacky answer (or really even specific code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (and lots of other people) would advocate flexbox. Read up on it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Unfortunately, flexbox currently has no way to evenly space out its children. `space-between` spaces them out as much as possible and `space-around` spaces them out as little as possible.

What does work just as well is giving the children `flex-grow: 1`, also making the children flexboxes and then center aligning whatever's in those.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="stuff">
      <h3>asdf</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="stuff">
      <h3>asdf</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="stuff">
      <h3>asdf</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

.cell {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stuff {
  background: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8s4zazk/

Comment: Very helpful--thanks! I was suspecting something with flex might work (should've mentioned that), but didn't consider making each item a flex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a css flexbox solution:

HTML

```
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item image-wrapper">inner1</div>
  <div class="Aligner-item text-wrapper">inner2</div>
  <div class="Aligner-item text-wrapper">inner3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Aligner {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


.Aligner-item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-wrapper{
  height: 200px;
}

.text-wrapper{
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use grid, use **space evenly** is slightly different to space around and space between. I prefer space evenly.